# Missing nodes in XML DOM - simple example

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

[How the XML table should render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yn0b.png)

The table **won't render** because the .XML doc is missing a node for QUANTITY in UNIT 3.

**How do we skip missing nodes in XML DOM?**

The XML doc (example.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CUSTOMER_ORDER>
    <UNIT>
        <ID>Unit 1</ID>
        <QUANTITY>45</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE>25.99</PRICE>
    </UNIT>
    <UNIT>
        <ID>Unit 2</ID>
        <QUANTITY>209</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE>9.95</PRICE>
    </UNIT>
    <UNIT>
        <ID>Unit 3</ID>   <!-- The QUANTITY node for Unit 3 is missing -->
        <PRICE>14.99</PRICE>
    </UNIT>
    <UNIT>
        <ID>Unit 4</ID>
        <QUANTITY>156</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE>35.88</PRICE>
    </UNIT>
    <UNIT>
        <ID>Unit 5</ID>
        <QUANTITY>25</QUANTITY>
        <PRICE>199.00</PRICE>
    </UNIT>
</CUSTOMER_ORDER>
```

Here's the XML DOM (with HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 2px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>

<body onload="loadXMLDoc()">

<table id="test"></table>

<script>
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     testFunction(xmlhttp);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "example.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function testFunction(xml) {
  var table="<tr><th>Unit</th><th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>";
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var i;
  var y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("UNIT");
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) 
  {
  var u = y[i].getElementsByTagName("ID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var p = y[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
  var q = y[i].getElementsByTagName("QUANTITY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    table += "<tr><td>" +
    u +                         // Unit ID column
    "</td><td>" +
    p +                         // PRICE column
    "</td><td>" +
    q +                         // QUANTITY column
    "</td></tr>";
   }
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's your own code that assumes there'll always be a "QUANTITY" element. Just check to see if any exist before looking for the value.

Comment: That seems to be a reasonable solution. How would you do that?

Comment: Just test to see if `y[i].getElementsByTagName("QUANTITY").length` is at least `1` before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Pointy said check if there is a quantity before setting *q* if the *QUANTITY* is missing then set the default to 1 or whatever value you wish.

---

Replace this:

```
var q = y[i].getElementsByTagName("QUANTITY")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

---

with:

```
var qElem = y[i].getElementsByTagName("QUANTITY"); //Get quantity elems
var q = (qElem.length > 0) ? qElem[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue : 1; //Check if there is anything in qElem if not set q to 1
```

This should work.

Comment: Incredible! Thanks for this perfect answer.

Comment: Glad I could help.